# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (chrome) & SyntaxError: missing } after function body (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I get two different errors pointing to two different parts of the code, chrome point to the first line and firefox pointing to the last.

This started after I added the following lines:

```
var year = 0;
var total_customer = 0;

function cgr() {
    for (var year = 0; (churn * total_customer) < leadcon; year++) {
        total_customer = total_customer + leadcon;
    }

function car() {
    if (!isNaN(year)) {
        $("#car").html(year);
    } else {
        $("#car").html("error");
    }
    return;
}
```

full script is here: http://pastebin.com/NnHq5PnR

wondering what is causing the error and why the debug is so unclear?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace at the end of the `cgr()` function. If you use a text editor with syntax highlighting and/or tabbed your code properly this would be easy to spot.

Comment: ended up retoring an old version and the error is gone, must have made a typo that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the end curly bracket } for cgr function.

```
var year = 0,
    total_customer = 0;

function cgr() {
  for (var year = 0; (churn * total_customer) < leadcon; year++) {
      total_customer = total_customer + leadcon;
  }
}

function car() {
  if (!isNaN(year)) {
      $("#car").html(year);
  } else {
    $("#car").html("error");
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I added the curly bracket, however the error still persists, same error.

Comment: Have you you checked you JavaScript code with a linter? Here is a link to an online linter: http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php